# MONGO_FDW on Postgres user privileges

Tags: postgresql, mongodb

Setting up MONGO_FDW in Postgres for the first time.

First step is to add the extension after connecting as the default `postgres` user:

`CREATE EXTENSION mongo_fdw;`

The application user is `app_user`, so I grant this:

`GRANT CREATE  SERVER TO app_user;`

I then connect as `app_user` and issue:

```
CREATE  SERVER "app_rem_db"
    FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER mongo_fdw
    OPTIONS (
        address 'localhost',
        port '27017'
    );
```

But I get the error:

`ERROR:  foreign-data wrapper "mongo_fdw" does not exist`

If however I run the `CREATE SERVER` as `postgres` it works.

How do I allow other users to create the server?

Continuing with the `postgres` user though, I next create the USER MAPPING:

```
CREATE USER MAPPING FOR app_user
    SERVER "app_rem_db"
    OPTIONS (username 'app_user_pg', password 'hello123');
```

If I then again connect as `app_user` and try to create a foreign table I get (The mongoDB has a database `mongo_test` and a collection `testcol` therein):

```
CREATE FOREIGN TABLE mongo_testtab
(
    data JSON
)
SERVER "app_rem_db"
OPTIONS (database 'mongo_test', collection 'testcol');
```

I again get an error:

`ERROR:  server "app_rem_db" does not exist`

If I switch back to `postgres` user I can create the foreign table.

But then when I try to query the table I get:

```
select * from mongo_testtab;
ERROR:  relation "mongo_testtab" does not exist
LINE 1: select * from mongo_testtab;
```

Comment: Perhaps the `app_user`'s `search_path` is set differently from that of `postgres`, and it looks for the objects in a different schema (namespace)?

Comment: You are connecting to different databases (foreign data wrappers don't live in a schema).

Comment: @mustaccio is there a way to get the `app_user` to be able to create the server?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe perhaps if I could find a way to create the fdw server in the `app_user` database/schema that would help, but even granting `CREATE SERVER TO app_user` doesn't make it so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extension must be created as superuser, there is no way around that. When you create the extension, make sure that you connect to the correct database (not to `postgres`).

Then there are two options:

1. You grant the `app_user` the `USAGE` privilege on the FDW:

   ```
   GRANT USAGE ON FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER mongo_fdw TO app_user;
   ```

   Then you can create the foreign server as `app_user`.

   - advantage: you need fewer actions as superuser
   - disadvantage: you modify an object that belongs to the extension, which will get lost during dump/restore
2. You create the foreign server as superuser, then grant `app_user` the `USAGE` privilege on the foreign server:

   ```
   GRANT USAGE ON FOREIGN SERVER app_rem_db TO app_user;
   ```

   - advantage: you don't modify extension objects
   - disadvantage: more jobs to be done as superuser

Comment: Thanks this helped. I  switch to the app_users db `\c app_db` as `postgres` then ran the `CREATE EXTENSION mongo_fdw  WITH SCHEMA app_schem`. Then connected as `app_user` and was then able to complete the process. Thanks for your help.